# How to fix errors when using opl.end() in main flow control loop

Tags: cplex, opl, cp-optimizer

I'm batch running tens of thousands of tests using a loop inside a `main` flow control block. Each run of the loop spawns a new OPL model using the designated `.dat` data file and `.mod` model file (which is separate from the batch runner `.mod` file which solely contains the `main` flow control block).

Because every run of the loop creates a new model, the memory usage builds and builds until it eventually crashes the IDE when I don't use `.end()` statements to close all of the data structures created for each test. While most of the data structures close just fine, I've found that `opl.end();` crashes the tester.

**How do I close the OPL models without crashing the tester?**

I've tried both the oplide application and the `oplrun` command line interface, both on macOS and Windows (though I need to run the tests on Windows in the end). I'm using CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.9.

I create the objects using:

```
// Create new model
var source = new IloOplModelSource("model-file.mod");
var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
var cp = new IloCP();
var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cp);

// Set next test case as data source
var testCasePath = thisOplModel.TestCaseFilenames[testNumber];
var data = new IloOplDataSource(testCasePath);
opl.addDataSource(data);

// Generate model
opl.generate();
```

And I attempt to close them when I'm done by using:

```
data.end();
opl.end(); // Causes it to crash
cp.end();
def.end();
source.end();
```

---

**Edited to add more specific information:**
I'm running an RCPSP scheduling problem, using my own model which is a modified version of the built-in example.

Here's a stripped-down version of the code I'm using. I created a run configuration containing just this batch runner `.mod` file, with the model file and data files it references stored elsewhere:

```
using CP;

// Import test case filename data
int NumberOfFiles = 3;
range FileIDs = 0..NumberOfFiles-1;
string TestCaseFilenames[FileIDs] = ["TestCase-01.dat", "TestCase-02.dat", "TestCase-03.dat"];

main {
  var testCaseDirectory = "~/Desktop/TestCases/";

  // Solve each test case in the list
  for (var testNumber = 0; testNumber < thisOplModel.NumberOfFiles; testNumber++) {
    // Create new model
    var source = new IloOplModelSource("RCPSP.mod");
    var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
    var cp = new IloCP();
    var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cp);

    // Set CP parameters
    cp.param.TimeLimit = 5; // Number is in seconds
    cp.param.Workers = 4; // Number of computer cores used
    cp.param.TimeMode = "ElapsedTime"; // How to report time 
    cp.param.LogVerbosity = "Quiet"; // How much to write to the engine log

    // Set next test case as data source
    var testCaseFilename = thisOplModel.TestCaseFilenames[testNumber];
    var testCasePath = testCaseDirectory + testCaseFilename;
    var data = new IloOplDataSource(testCasePath);
    opl.addDataSource(data);

    // Generate model
    opl.generate();

    // Report test case name to script log for progress visibility
    writeln(testNumber+1 + ") Solving " + opl.TestCaseFilename + "...");

    // Solve model
    if (cp.solve()) { // Successfully found solution
      // Run solution validation code in model file's post-processing execute statement
        // If a solution is invalid, the entire bath runner will fail with an error at that test and line
      opl.postProcess();

      // Report some solve-dependent results to oplide log for visibility
      writeln(" - UB = " + cp.getObjValue() + ", LB = " + cp.getObjBound()); // Makespan
    } else { // Failed to find solution
      // Report no solution to oplide log for visibility
      writeln(" - No solution found.")
      writeln(" - Lower Bound = " + cp.getObjBound());
    }

    // Report some results to script log for visibility
    writeln(" - Status = " + cp.status); // Solver status
    writeln(" - Solve Time = " + cp.info.SolveTime + " sec"); // Time spent solving

    // End processes to prevent memory leaks
    data.end();
    opl.end(); // Causes it to crash
    cp.end();
    def.end();
    source.end();
  }

  // Confirm to user that tests are complete
  writeln();
  writeln("All done!");
}
```

Here's what the output should be (produced by commenting out the `opl.end()` line):

```
1) Solving TestCase-01.dat...
 - UB = 48, LB = 48
 - Status = 2
 - Solve Time = 1.299999952 sec
2) Solving TestCase-02.dat...
 - UB = 65, LB = 36
 - Status = 1
 - Solve Time = 5.019999981 sec
3) Solving TestCase-03.dat...
 - No solution found.
 - LB = 1
 - Status = 0
 - Solve Time = 5.010000229 sec

All done!
```

Instead, it just logs this output:

```
1) Solving TestCase-01.dat...
 - UB = 48, LB = 48
 - Status = 2
 - Solve Time = 1.299999952 sec
```

and then pops up a window with this error message:

> Oplrun process is not responding, you must relaunch the Run Configuration.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem here. I tried your code with the shipped `steelmill` example in a loop and it did not crash. What version do you use? Can you provide a minimal code that reproduces the crash? Can you show the exact error message and/or a backtrace? Also, have you tried setting `thisOplModel.settings.mainEndEnabled = true` and/or `opl.settings.mainEndEnabled = true`?

Comment: Edited to add more information!

Comment: Sent! Let me know if you received it so I know it went to the right place. We should post back here once we've resolved it so others can learn from it too.

Comment: I got your email and replied to it (I found the problem). I will delete the comment that contains my email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We sorted this out by email. The reason for the crash is a bug in OPL. The problematic part of the code is something like this:

```
tuple T {
  key int id;
  int intArray[0..0];
}

{T} tuples = ...;

T tupleById[1..1];
execute {
  for (var t in tuples)
    tupleById[t.id] = t;
}
```

The problem is the assigment of a tuple that contains an array or set member in scripting. This triggers a bug in OPL that then eventually leads to a crash. A workaround is to initialize `tupleById` without scripting via

```
T tupleById[id in 1..1] = first({ t | t in tuples : t.id == id});
```

The trick here is that all the generated sets are singletons as ids are unique. We then use the [first()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/tlr_oplf_first.html) function to extract the first element from the singleton sets to get plain tuples.